# Methods for video rendering in popular Android video players

Tags: android, video

Videos are encoded in YUV color space. Android API supports only RGB out of the box. How popular Android video players as VPlayer or MX Player solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

2 general solutions:

1. Use a pure software algorithm to convert YUV -> RGB.
2. Use 3D shader hardware to do the heavy lifting to convert YUV -> RGB.

Also, question whether this is the optimal approach (i.e., this implies that you are decoding the video in software)-- should you do that? Can the hardware handle it instead (and display it at the same time)?

Comment: _Use 3D shader hardware to do the heavy lifting to convert YUV -> RGB._
I tried it with using shader with glTexSubImage2D. It was even slower than software YUV->RGB converting . And I saw artefacts in HD videos when some parts of the screen were from one frame and some from another(Maybe it was due to the lags). I've heard that glTexSubImage2D is not pretty slow itself because it uses copying texture data from RAM to GPU memory(but I could be wrong).

Comment: _Use a pure software algorithm to convert YUV -> RGB._
This principle uses CPU and this is inacceptible for me, because I also use ffmpeg for decode frames from video at the same time.

Comment: What kind of hardware are you using? That might influence the speed.

Comment: I use HTC Desire(Android 2.3, but without extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external)

Answer (score 0):

Most of them use ffmpeg to decode the audio/video:

https://sites.google.com/site/mxvpen/ffmpeg

https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/How%20to%20compile%20FFmpeg%20for%20Android

Comment: FFMPEG offers converting YUV->RGB throgh sws_scale function but it's very slow.

Comment: MX Player uses and I also used it on an app and it worked fine for me!

Comment: You had similar displaying framerate like MX player on HD videos?

Answer (score 0):

in opencv, you can do this

```
cv::Mat myuv(height + height / 2, width, CV_8UC1, (unsigned char *) mem);
cv::Mat bgr(width, height, CV_8UC3);
cv::cvtColor(myuv, bgr, CV_YUV420sp2RGB, 3);
```